# Add to cart button hidden in the CSS

Tags: css

I'm having some trouble on our website. The add to cart button is invisible and unclickable(obviously). When inspecting the element in my browser of where it should be, I can find the code for it and when checking the CSS for it, it's because it's hidden, obviously when un-ticking the part of CSS that makes it hidden, it comes back how it should be. How would I do this in the admin Magento so that it is globally back to "normal".

Comment: please accept your own answer to close the question :)

Answer (score 1):

Fixed. Went to cPanel skin/frontend/ultimo/default/css/override-components.css and commented out the line ".btn-cart {visibility: hidden;}"